# How to force typescript to require to return undefined rather than having an explicit return?

Tags: typescript

Let's take this example:

```js
function maybeString(a: number): string | undefined {
    if (a > 5) {
        return 'ok';
    }
}
```

This is valid Typescript.

Is there a configuration to force this code to be:

```js
function maybeString(a: number): string | undefined {
    if (a > 5) {
        return 'ok';
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

So always making the `return undefined` necessary and explicit?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return is somewhat close but not entirely what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally that should already lead to a TS error ([link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYE8BGBTAylAJxjAHMAKVALkTBGRwIEpqBnQ4kxAH0XABNswYtj6IA3gChE0xDGCIKiAHyIArI3FSZ2gtiggCSAORwA1kYDcW6QF8JdiaEiwEiFtggI+AWQw58RKQU1LT02Eys7KTcvGACQmAimtpyCqjKahqS2jp6BsZmltaINojYADbuyTnSuvqGsfHCfFbadjZAA)). The error should be "Not all code paths return a value.ts(7030)".

Maybe check your tsconfig file and set "noImplicitReturns" to true. If not yet true, this should enable such warnings.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitReturns": true
  }
}
```